# do not allow negative values in int property MVC C#

Tags: c#

I do have a strongly typed view in MVC C# in which the user has to enter a int value, the property is

```
 [Required(ErrorMessage="especificar correlativo")]
    [Display(Name = "Correlativo")]
    [Range(1, 9999, ErrorMessage = "correlativo no valido")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^(((\d{1})*))$", ErrorMessage = "correlativo no valido")]
    public int correlativo1
    {
        get { return Correlativo1; }
        set { Correlativo1 = value; }
    }
```

but my problem is that when the vies displays, the input lets the user specifies a negative value via the arrows at the right of the input

[image]

and yes it shows the validation message

[image]

but I don´t want (since the very beggining) let the user to have the option of specifies negative values.

this is the input in the view

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.correlativo1, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.correlativo1, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control left-border-none", @id = "idCorrelativo", @title = "especifique correlativo de licitación", @Value = ViewBag.correlativo } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.correlativo1, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
```

could you please tell me how to fix it?

Comment: Are you asking how to prevent a negative value from ever being entered in the control in the browser?

Comment: yes or at least do not present the arrows at the right side of the control

Comment: This may be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24246290/how-to-set-numeric-editorfor-min-max-and-default-values-in-razor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, see if adding a `min` attribute to your editor will work.  Basically want to render: `min="0"` in your final HTML.  So in your code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-2">
         @Html.LabelFor(model => model.correlativo1, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
         @Html.EditorFor(model => model.correlativo1, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control left-border-none", @id = "idCorrelativo", @title = "especifique correlativo de licitación", @Value = ViewBag.correlativo, @min="0" } })
         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.correlativo1, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

You can also use this to add the `max` attribute as well (if needed)

Answer (score 3):

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.correlativo1, new { htmlAttributes = new { @min = 0, @max = 9999, @class = "form-control left-border-none", @id = "idCorrelativo", @title = "especifique correlativo de licitación", @Value = ViewBag.correlativo } })
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very experienced with MVC but you could consider one of the following.

If negative values are invalid then perhaps you may want to consider using an unsigned int rather than an int.

Or..
Change the `set` of your property to prevent values lower than 0.

```
public int correlativo1
{
    get { return Correlativo1; }
    set
    { 
        if (value >= 0)
            Correlativo1 = value;
        else
            Correlativo1 = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't address the question being asked. Be careful and learned about the topic first before posting an answer.